# How to get detailed error msg from monetdbe_query

Tags: sql, monetdb

Looking at the C examples for monetdbe_query in the GitHub repository: https://github.com/MonetDBSolutions/monetdbe-examples

The prescribed way to run queries is to run SQL queries in an IF statement that captures Null return values as shown below:

```
if (monetdbe_query(db, "SELECT * FROM mystrings", &result, NULL) != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to run select query\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }
```

is it possible to get any detailed information regarding why the SQL statement failed?

Answer (score 0):

Many `monetdbe_` functions return an error message if something went wrong, or `NULL` otherwise. So, just catch the return value. See the example `copy_into.c` in [monetdbe-examples](https://github.com/MonetDBSolutions/monetdbe-examples):

```
if((err=monetdbe_query(db, sql, NULL, NULL)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\r\n", err);
    return -1;
}
```

`grep` for `err` in the examples for more.